# Problem installing monogame.extended package

Tags: c#, monogame

I am having a problem installing monogame extended while running
 `Install-Package MonoGame.Extended`
at nuget console.
I get this error :

```
unable to find package "Monogame.Extended"
```

I am using visual studio community 2017,
I have already opened a new monogame project.

Comment: Check the source, the command works in nuget.org

Comment: This could be an issue of case sensitivity try `dotnet add package MonoGame.Extended`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for it manually, click on Project ->  Manage Nuget Packages.
Then Browse and type in "Monogame.Extended"
You can also install it from here.